# TensorFlow GPU version instead of CPU version in Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

How do I use TensorFlow GPU version instead of CPU version in PyCharm (or other environment)?

Answer (score 0):

By default, as of TensorFlow 2.1 (regardless of PyCharm or whatever env you're coding in), TensorFlow installs the CPU+GPU package together. For older versions (which I do not recommend), you can explicitly use `pip install tensorflow` (old CPU versions) or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`

If you want to use the CPU instead of GPU, you can do the following:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf //tf now uses CPU
```

In this way, you can force TF to use only the CPU, even if you have can normally use  the GPU.